# How to set an AlarmManager in a Service in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a question in regards to the setting an AlarmManager within a service. I have created an AlarmManager which will start a service which then perform certain network activity(gets some time data) and then straight after that network performance, this service should set alarm based on the time data obtained from the web services. Now I have this main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 44);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, 
            intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

And this receiver that starts a service:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, PrayerTimeService.class);
    context.startService(i);

}
```

And this service:

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is sunning",  
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new SetTimeTask().execute(URL_ISLAMICFINDER);
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class SetTimeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    .... some network jobs
}
```

and now I have to set an alarmmanager here in the service how do I do that?

**UPDATE** added AlarmManager:
     //These are field in the service to get the time data as string
        private String morningTimeValue;
    private String sunriseValue;
    private String noonTimeValue;
    private String afternoonTimeValue;
    private String eveningTimeValue;
    private String nightTimeValue;
        //interger values used in conversion
        int morningTimeHour; 
        int fajrTimeMin;

```
//this is a method in the service and will be called in the onPostExecute();
public void setTimesForEvery(int hour, int min) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmForEvery.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}

//this method converts the string time to integer values
public void convertTime(String time, int hour, int min) {
    String[] array = time.split(":");
    String h = array[0];
    String m = array[1];
    hour = Integer.parseInt(h);
    min = Integer.parseInt(m);      
}

// this is asynctask
private class SetTimeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        setPrayerTimes(urls[0]);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), fajrTimeValue + "|" + 
        zuhurTimeValue + "|" +asrTimeValue + "|" + maghribTimeValue + "|" +  
        ishaTimeValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        convertTime(fajrTimeValue, morningTimeHour, fajrTimeMin);

        setTimesForEvery(21, 45);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);
```

Comment: Is this code going to be in service? if yes in whiche Method?

Comment: Without service you can use this code. It working successfully for me.

Comment: but I am starting the service just to get data from the web for example, I will get a time 09:30 in the AsyncTask and now I need to set an AlarmManager to notify the user at 9:30, and this time can be changed next day depending on the web service provider and so on, so the whole point of useing the service is to get the time. So my first AlarmManager is workig fine and it starts the service and Now I am in a situation to set new AlarmManager to schedule new time in that service using the time data got from the web.

Answer (score 0):

My suggession is You Should not Write your alarm manager in the service. It should be inside the "Alarm" Broadcast receiver

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, PrayerTimeService.class);
        context.startService(i);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,arg1,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*60*24 ,pendingIntent);

}
```

if you want to use alarm manager set inside the servie. you can use it inside the "onCreate" method or "onStart" method of Service

Comment: how do i get the time data from the web and set them?

Comment: oh... if you want to get the time and date and set it to the Alarm manager, then implement your code to get the time an date inside the doInBackground() method and return the result, then catch the result at the onPostExecute() method of the "SetTimeTask" AsynckTask class and set to the Alarm manager... if you have problems in implementing this.. I can help you.. first try out yourself.

Comment: ok I am working on it if not then I will post here to ask help thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Dehan, I have just updated my post, but it is not working, can you have a look?

Comment: setTimesForEvery(21, 45); this line of code is just hardcoded to test so if successful the realtime will be loaded

Comment: friend... you are passing "hour" and "min" as parameters.. and you didn't return them.. no point of using this method.you cant do like this.. you are not passing string object references... 
can you please change your variable names to english names.. then it will be more clear..

Comment: I have changed the code a little, so the names, but I don't know how to do the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setTimesForEvery(String time) {

    String[] array = time.split(":");
    String h = array[0];
    String m = array[1];
    hour = Integer.parseInt(h);
    min = Integer.parseInt(m);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmForEvery.class);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),cal.getTimeInMillis, pi);


}
```

your complete requirement is not clear. but do these things and try again.
put super.onPostExecute() line in the top of the onPostExecute() method.

and return the value of "setPrayerTimes(urls[0])" this method to the onPostExecute() and parse the value as time parameter.

any thing going wrong, inbox me your complete requirement with clear description in english.